# bootstrap accordion in asp.net toggle doesn't work at all

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry but another bootstrap question, but after 1 1/2 days battling this, I hoped that maybe someone can help me with this.

I have an asp.net 4.5 web form with a bootstrap menu, tabs (they work great!)
During a mobile view I wanted to display an accordion instead of the tabs.

I created a new section and followed the code in bootstraps example, and cannot get it to toggle.  When I click on a link nothing happens.

I changed one of the accordion sections to accordion-body collapse in, so that one would section would be open, hoping maybe it would work them.

No luck.  It is open when first opening, but once you click on another accordion header, the open one closes and nothing will open.

```
    <section class="hidden-desktop visible-tablet visible-phone">
        <div id="accordion2" class="accordion">

            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#acServ">Services
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="acServ" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <div>
                            Services
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#acSched">Scheduling
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="acSched" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <div>
                            Scheduling
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#acClient">Clients
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="acClient" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <div>
                            Clients
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#acForm">Formulas
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="acForm" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">

                        <div>
                            Formulas
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#acProd">Products
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="acProd" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">

                        <div>
                            Products
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#acAbout">About
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="acAbout" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">

                        <div>
                            About
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#acStart">Get Started
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="acStart" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">

                        <div>
                            Get Started
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Anyone have any ideas of what is going on?

Oh yes, the scripts are ordered like...

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
```

and the css is like...

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Site.css is some simple changes, (i.e. Colors) I made to bootstrap.css tabs.

Comment: Your code works in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M54af/.

Comment: It does not answer your question but I don't think that you need bootstrap-collapse.js and bootstrap-transition.js.They are all included in bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Yes, it does in jsfiddle.  Any ideas on conflicts related to asp.net web forms using a master page?

Comment: Are you using the accordion inside an Updatepanel, if yes, please try to check the accordion by placing it outside of the updatepanel. If it is working, then please let me know, I have a solution for this issue.

Comment: The mobile view, are you testing on a browser? if so which one? I had problems after migrating to ASP.Net, scripts failed to work on IE. Might be a similar problem.